# Independence of Sum and Difference of Random Variables[CSIR-UGC NET]

Tags: probability, self-study, correlation, joint-distribution

> Let X and Y be independent and identically distributed random variables such that $P(X=0)=P(X=1)=0.5, W=|X-Y| $ and $Z=X+Y$ . Then which statement is not correct?

1. X and W are independent .
2. Y and W are independent.
3. Z and W are uncorrelated .
4. Z and W are independent.

I think the answer is option 4, but am unable to obtain a proof. How to calculate the expectation of W and Z?

Comment: Please add `[self-study]` tag and check http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info to read about out policy for such questions

Comment: You can calculate the expectations by working out the probability of each outcome and then using the definition of expectation.

Comment: The OP's chosen _nom-de-plume_ means _student_ in Sanskrit and in this instance, the student got his homework done for him by @StatsPlease.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I'm afraid this isnt a standard homework problem. The problem was asked in a prior examination, which I have mentioned in the title. Anyway, it is not that I required a complete solution, just hints. I am just a beginner in stats and maybe not be as expert as you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's option 4.

We know that the following is true:

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
X & Y & W=|{X-Y}| & Z=X+Y & p\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.25\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0.25\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.25\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0.25
\end{array}$

From this, we know that:

If $W=1$ then $Z=1$ (converse also applies).

If $Z\neq 1$ then $W=0$.

If $W=0$ then $Z=\{0,2\}  \text{ wp } 0.5$.

Therefore they are not independent as information about one will help determine the other.

Alternatively, we know that two random variables are independent if $\mathbb{P}[A\cap B]=\mathbb{P}[A]\mathbb{P}[B]$.

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
A & B & \mathbb{P}[A] &\mathbb{P}[B] & \mathbb{P}[A]\mathbb{P}[B] & \mathbb{P}[A\cap B]\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.25 & 0.125 & 0.25\\
0 & 1 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.25 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0.5 & 0.25 & 0.125 & 0.25\\
1 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.25 & 0.125 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.25 & 0.5\\
1 & 2 & 0.5 & 0.25 & 0.125 & 0\\
\end{array}$

As you can see, $\mathbb{P}[A\cap B]\neq\mathbb{P}[A]\mathbb{P}[B]$, therefore they are not independent.